# Phonegap worked fine but now it isn't

Tags: javascript, cordova

A strange thing is happend with cordova, even the simpliest code doesn't work anymore. The code worked fine enough but since yesterday it isn't. I didn't change anything in the manifest.xml or any other file. Is it my device?

```
<title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    function onload(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('test')
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
         console.log('test');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
                'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova + '<br />' +
                'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                'Device Model: '    + device.model     + '<br />' +
                'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

</script>
```

Now I can't run cordova anymore. This is what I get in `logcat`:

```
05-15 11:46:33.478: I/CordovaLog(26092): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
05-15 11:46:33.478: I/CordovaLog(26092): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
05-15 11:46:33.478: D/CordovaLog(26092): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
05-15 11:46:33.478: I/CordovaLog(26092): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
05-15 11:46:33.478: D/CordovaLog(26092): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
05-15 11:46:33.483: I/CordovaLog(26092): Found preference for loadingDialog=MORE, Loading...
05-15 11:46:33.483: D/CordovaLog(26092): Found preference for loadingDialog=MORE, Loading...
05-15 11:46:33.503: D/JsMessageQueue(26092): Set native->JS mode to 2
05-15 11:46:33.508: D/DroidGap(26092): DroidGap.init()
05-15 11:46:33.618: D/CordovaWebView(26092): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-15 11:46:33.618: D/PluginManager(26092): init()
05-15 11:46:33.623: D/CordovaWebView(26092): >>> loadUrlNow()
05-15 11:46:33.628: D/DroidGap(26092): Resuming the App
05-15 11:46:33.688: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(26092): Ignore this event
05-15 11:46:33.698: D/DroidGap(26092): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-15 11:46:34.088: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(26092): Ignore this event
05-15 11:46:36.068: D/Cordova(26092): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-15 11:46:36.068: D/DroidGap(26092): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
05-15 11:46:36.068: D/DroidGap(26092): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-15 11:46:38.068: D/DroidGap(26092): onMessage(spinner,stop)
05-15 11:46:38.353: W/dalvikvm(26092): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
```

What is wrong?

Comment: :clear cache of your device and then try again

Comment: It works now. But the getcurrentposition won't work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

The phonegap plugins: camera, accelerator etc. works but the geolocation not.
This is the code all permissions are installed like before:

```
<title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log('test');
        alert('test');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        element.innerHTML =
                'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                'Timestamp: '          +                                   position.timestamp          + '<br />';
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

</script>
```

But the variable "position" isn't set or something, this plugin was working before now it ain't. :(